# Activerecord relationships

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I have following modles in my application..

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts
end

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

My requirement is that a user can subscribe to many posts and i want to use `has_many :through` relationship, as i want to have an extra attribute `subscription_type` in joining table.
User has many to many relationship with post.

Please tell me the best way to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quite simple:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :subscriptions
  has_many :posts, :trough => :subscriptions
end

class Subscription< ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :post

  # add subscription_type to db columns
  # also user_id and post_id
end

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :subscriptions
  has_many :users, :trough => :subscriptions
end
```

Comment: Matzi, how we can distinguish between posts that user has created and posts that users has subscribed?

Comment: Create another subscription_type for creators, or add a user_id to Post model and link it to the User model.

Comment: can't we have associations in user model like this.... (has_many :posts) and (has_many :subscribed_posts, :class_name => 'Post', :through => :subscriptions)

Comment: Sure you can. The ID's will be all okay, so no reason not to do it.

Comment: but when i do this... user.posts returns me all the post that user had created.. and user.subscribed_posts returns me some association errors :(